# Vue.js with Vuex, and custom components, @click method outputs undefined

Tags: javascript, internationalization, vue.js

I've a menu with *about*, *news* and *contact* buttons in addition to three buttons that allow to change the language of the label on the menu's buttons and the content of the text elements (variable `contentText` below).

I'm using **Vue.js** with custom components, as well as **[Vuex.js](http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html)** to store language states. I'm being able to select the language of the labels on the menu buttons. For instance, if I click on the button labeled *fr*, the labels on the meny bar change from *about* to *à propos*, *news* to *nouvelles*, etc., but for some reason that I cannot identify, **when I click any one of the menu buttons, the click event doesn't trigger the visibility of the respective text elements**. The code that deals with states is something along the following lines (Jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/674z6w0h/11/)):

```
Vue.use(Vuex)
var storelang = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    lang: {}
  },
  actions: {
    lang: 'code'
  },
  mutations: {
    code(state, ln) {
       var jsontext = '{"aboutMenu":"About", "aboutText":"This is just a small text in English.", "newsMenu":"News", "newsText":"News written in the English language.", "contactMenu":"Contact", "contactText":"Contact info written in English."}'
      if (ln === 'pt') {
        jsontext = '{"aboutMenu":"Sobre", "aboutText":"Isto é um pequeno texto em Português.", "newsMenu":"Novidades", "newsText":"Novidades escritas em Português.", "contactMenu":"Contactar", "contactText":"Informação de contacto escrita em Português."}'
      }
      if (ln === 'fr') {
        jsontext = '{"aboutMenu":"À propos", "aboutText":"Ceci est juste um petit texte en Français.", "newsMenu":"Nouvelles", "newsText":"Des nouvelles écrites en Français.", "contactMenu":"Contacter", "contactText":"Des informations dans la langue Française."}'
      }
      state.lang = JSON.parse(jsontext)
    }
  },
  strict: true
})
```

The components with their respective templates, created with `Vue.extend`:

```
var contentBtn = Vue.extend({
  template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="toggleAbout">{{lang.aboutMenu}}</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="toggleNews">{{lang.newsMenu}}</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" @click="toggleContact">{{lang.contactMenu}}</button>'
})

var contentTxt = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div v-show="aboutIsVisible">{{lang.aboutText}}</div><div v-show="newsIsVisible">{{lang.newsText}}</div><div v-show="contactIsVisible">{{lang.contactText}}</div>'
})

var langBtn = Vue.extend({
  template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent=activate("en")>en</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent=activate("pt")>pt</button><button  type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent=activate("fr")>fr</button>',
  methods: {
    activate: function(x) {
      storelang.actions.lang(x)
    }
  },
  ready: function() {
    return storelang.actions.lang('en') //default language
  }
})
```

And my `Vue` instance, where I store the values concerning the visiblity of the text elements, register the components and declare the methods for the click events:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    aboutIsVisible: true,
    newsIsVisible: true,
    contactIsVisible: true
  },
  components: {
    'langbtn': langBtn,
    'contentbtn': contentBtn,
    'contenttxt': contentTxt
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAbout: function () {
      this.aboutIsVisible = !this.aboutIsVisible
    },
    toggleNews: function () {
      this.newsIsVisible = !this.newsIsVisible
    },
    toggleContact: function () {
      this.contactIsVisible = !this.contactIsVisible
    }
  }
})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call `toggleNews` on a child component that doesn't have a method called `toggleNews`.  That method is on the parent component.  You'll need to move the button into the parent element, or utilize events to broadcast clicks from the child elements up to the parent.

I moved the child templates up into the parent and your code is working as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/674z6w0h/13/

Comment: Of course that's it! Thank you so much (once again) :-)

Comment: no problem! Here is what it will look like if you want only one tab visible at a time: https://jsfiddle.net/674z6w0h/14/

Comment: that's absolutely awesome! I was gonna try to fix that just now, not as half as quick though eheheh